# iPhone process a swipe by user

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, swipe, iphone-sdk-4.1

Simple question here: How can I detect when I user swipes their finger on the screen of the iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement a gesture recognizer in your application.

In your interface:

```
#define kMinimumGestureLength  30
#define kMaximumVariance   5
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface *yourView* : UIViewController {
    CGPoint gestureStartPoint;
}
@end
```

**kMinimumGestureLength** is the minimum distance the finger as to travel before it counts as a swipe. **kMaximumVariance** is the maximum distance, in pixels, that the finger can end above the beginning point on the y-axis.

Now open your interface `.xib` file and select your view in IB, and make sure `Multiple Touch` is enabled in `View Attributes.`

In your implementation, implement these methods.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
  }

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];    

    CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.x - currentPosition.x);
    CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.y - currentPosition.y);


  if(deltaX >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaY <= kMaximumVariance){
      //do something 
 }
else if(deltaY >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaX <= kMaximumVariance){
      //do something
   }
 }
```

This is one way to implement a swipe recognizer.  Also, you really should check out the Docs on this topic:

[UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You didn't explain kMinimumVariance.

Answer (score 3):

The UIGestureRecognizer is what you want. Especially the UISwipeGestureRecognizer subclass

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I was able to answer my own question: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009460

Thanks for the help everyone!